# what is the difference between upstream and downstream ports?

Tags: usb, display

I am considering purchasing a monitor which features USB 3.0 super-Speed Hub (with 1 x USB upstream port / 2 x USB3.0 and 2 x USB 2.0 downstream ports).

What does this mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

USB is asymmetric. From the hub's point of view, "upstream" is the connection to the PC (the USB host), while "downstream" refers to connections to the devices.